# Booking a rent-a-car through VPN (different location)

Tags: usa, budget, car-rentals, rental, florida

I got an idea the other day and wonder if it would be cheaper to make a booking for a rental car using a different IP location through a VPN service.

I am located in Denmark and would rent a car in USA (Key West, Florida) and say I use VPN server located in fx. Brazil or China (where ever).

Any experience with that?

Comment: Why do you think it'll make a difference in price? Your bank may refuse the foreign transaction, too.

Comment: Just as an FYI, if you are planning to stay only in Key West you don't need a rental car.

Comment: Sure, everyone does this all the time. (Roddy, they price by your origin, you pay more if you're richer country.)

Comment: To expand on @LaconicDroid's comment, Key West is 3km east to west, much of that space is taken up by the airport, and parking is at a premium. Everything you might want to visit is in walking distance; you might even be able to walk to your hotel/AirBnB from the airport. Unless you're going to be traveling up the overseas highway to other Florida keys, getting a rental car is probably not a good idea.

Comment: When renting a car for US travel I've had good experiences going through the company's Danish site. They usually include insurance for the same money that you'll pay on the US site for a rental without insurance.

Comment: You are able to get different rates by changing your country of residence on some rental sites. But I don't think this applies to air travel, does it? What will you do try 100 different countries to see what rates you get?

Comment: @LaconicDroid good point but we will be there for 2 weeks so gonna visit nearby cities as well :)

Comment: @Pepys Fair enough. In which case I'd only rent a car the days I was traveling as it's just a pain to have a vehicle when in you're in the Conch Republic.

Comment: @LaconicDroid why is so? I should def. read up more on this topic then

Comment: @Pepys Key West itself is a very small island, and parking is at a premium. The locals tend to cycle, and many places you will want to visit are within walking distance of each other (especially if you are staying in Old Town). If you need to travel further (i.e. across the island), cabs are plentiful and reasonably priced. And if you want to take advantage of all Duval Street has to offer, you won't want to drive anyway!

Comment: @LaconicDroid cool!! Thanks a lot for the valuable info. Cycling would be great :) Would consider renting a car just for the out of town tours

Comment: @Pepys If you want a very small flavour of traffic in Old Town, check out the [Sloppy Joe's Crowd Cam](https://sloppyjoes.com/conch-shell-cam/) or their [Duval Street Cam](https://liveduvalstreet.com/) - you will see the ratio of pedestrians vs cyclists vs cars vs cabs!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it may be very well worth to give it a try. Location based price differences are quite common in the travel industry and it is very much possible to save money by pretending to be somewhere else.

Seeing that you are from Denmark, a specific example would be the Color Line ferry from Hirtshals to Larvik tonight at 22:15. If you try to book two persons and a car on the Danish Color Line web site, they will offer you a ticket for DKK 815. If you try to book the same ticket from the Norwegian web site, you are offered the same ticket with the same conditions for DKK 640. On the Swedish site, the price is DKK 590 and on the German site they want DKK 730. To take advantage of these different prices, you don't even need a VPN service, but you can simply go to www.colorline.se instead of www.colorline.dk to get the cheapest ticket.

I don't see how any of the disadvantages listed by Burhan are likely to apply. Even if you are from or live in Denmark, it is not particularly unlikely that you actually are in Brazil or China when trying to rent a car in the US. Order forms are usually designed to cope with international customers, if your bank is declining credit card usage just because it seems as you are travelling, you should consider to change your bank and if you are offered payment options not applicable to you, then simply choose another applicable option.

Comment: Where I'm from, banks habitually decline credit card usage from unexpected countries; this is a totally standard anti-fraud mechanism (and frankly I'd consider changing banks if they _didn't_ do this!). You're expected to inform them if you're going to be travelling. Other than that, great answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That might be common in those few countries where most people never travel internationally like e.g. the US. It is elsewhere neither common, nor expected to inform your bank that you intend to use your cards in other countries, as this is one of main reasons why many customers get an internationally accepted bank card at all.

Comment: I'm in the UK and this has been standard practice for many years. People from the UK travel all the time. Anti-fraud mechanisms like this do not prevent you from travelling nor from using your card abroad; you just have to think ahead a little bit, which hopefully you're doing anyway before a trip. It is true that I cannot speak for banks in countries that are not the UK, but the basis on which you have rejected my anecdote is demonstrably false.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit From the first ten UK banking FAQs I can find on Google for international card usage (Halifax, Metro Bank, Co-Operative Bank, Lloyds Bank, Barclays, Santander, Natwest, HSBC, Bank of Scotland, Yorshire Bank), only Natwest and HSBC recommend, but do not require that you inform them about international usage. Most other banks explicitely remind their customers that it is not (or no longer) necessary to inform in advance about international card usage. It seems to be a common misconception in the UK that you are supposed to do so.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: In my experience with a French bank, it is simply that unless otherwise forewarned, the daily/weekly limits on the card are far lower internationally (out of EU) to prevent fraud. In case of travel, a simple e-mail to my advisor with the country and time period allows them to raise the limits for the specific country and time period.

Comment: Speaking as someone who has built credit card fraud detection models - pretty much every model is going to treat an out of country transaction with no notification as having increased risk.  Whether that increased risk causes them to actually reject the transaction is dependent on many, many other factors specific to that particular case, such that your anecdotal evidence is unlikely to be predictive of other people's experiences.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Your credit card issuer likely has no idea what your VPN IP address is...

Comment: I see a great discussion going on :) Thanks for the ferry example @Tor-EinarJarnbjo it is definitely worth the try. I will give it a shot these days and write again

Comment: @trognanders I'm not entirely convinced by that - Verified by Visa for example embeds a little pane in the merchant portal and I suspect it's precisely for this reason (among others) and it's your VPN's IP they'd see (i.e. in this case an IP from another country) though I would tend to agree that online transactions will be far more lenient than "card present" transactions so perhaps it's not a factor. Still, banks _do_ pass on travel notices to card issues in general so it's a thing at least for physical purchases with modern banks.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo It's not just international travel. Traveling a significant distance can cause a fraud alert, even within one state.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Declining transactions made from unexpected locations is bog standard in France or *the Netherlands*, a very small country where many many people travel abroad on a regular basis. Better banks now offer ways to switch these protections on or off online. It's plainly not true that it's only common in the US or on the way out. As usual, you prefer to engage in bad faith arguments to avoid changing even a comma instead of following a perfectly reasonable suggestion that would make an otherwise good answer even better. (+1 nonetheless)

Answer (score 5):

I have been doing this many times, for flights, rental cars, and hotels, and never had any issues with it. Often you can save a lot, but it is not always cheaper; and you have to be aware of country specific regulations (and potentialy speak other languages - sometimes prices change when you switch the language).
[Example: flights within Peru are extremely cheap for Peruvians (often -80% or more). If you try to book those with an IP from another country, you get warned that you need to a peruvian citizenship to use those tickets; if you come with a Peruvian IP, you get no such warning (and then the ticket won't allow to fly).]

The idea being discussed that 'your bank will decline it' makes no sense, as your bank doesn't care or even *know* how you were logged in to the website or if you are in person in the office - they see only that company X is trying to charge your credit card.
That might or might not raise a flag, depending on your bank, the amount, and your previous payment behavior, but it is completely unrelated to which IP address you used.

Answer (score 3):

Okay I did my "research" :)

**Short answer:** *yes* there is a difference in prices

**Long answer:**

I switched VPN servers (getting different IP everytime), used Microsoft Edge in private mode and cleared all cookies and cached data at every new search/ip change.

The search was for 10 days rental, Key West airport, Ford Mustang Convertible

***Rentalcars.com***

USA - 593$

Denmark - 516$ (no vpn)

Germany - 516

Bulgaria/Brazil/UK - 516$

***Expedia.com***

Australia - 616$

DK - 597$ (no vpn, general website, not location based)

DK - **465$** (no vpn, local website, expedia.dk)

US - 597$

UK - 523$

***Enterprise.com*** (not a search engine)

USA - 596$

DK - 612$

BG - 612$

So after all it seems that without VPN **and** using the website's local version (expedia.com mentioned above) is actually the cheapest option for me. 
It could be coincidence and it could be difference in their terms and conditions but at first glance it is the same deal I am getting from the same rental company.

Thanks to all that had something to say.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of issues with doing this, and getting a cheaper rate may not be the end result.

In short, don't do it because it won't help with the rates. Here are just some reasons why this is not recommended:

- You will see requirements for rental that do not apply to you. For example, you may see insurance or documentation requirements that are not applicable to you, which may end up costing you *more*.
- Your bank may refuse the charge.
- The website may offer you payment options that are not applicable to you.
- The forms you fill in may not be compatible with your information. For example, you may not be able to enter a billing address because there is no place to change the country; or you may not be able to enter a phone number because its expecting a US number.

The best way to get a deal on rental cars is:

- Rent from a location other than the airport. Airport locations usually have a surcharge.
- Look at your credit card for loyalty points or upgrades for rentals.
- Try to pay upfront for the rental - many companies offer deep discounts for this.
- Look at the airline, they may offer a rental reference code or preferred rates for your booking.
- Use alternative means of renting (like [Turo](https://turo.com)).

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree with the first four points.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why your bank would refuse the charge. Your _bank_ won't be able to tell that you used a VPN... and they wouldn't care, anyway.

Comment: Looks like you made up most of the bullet points.

Comment: @only_pro The bank may not refuse the charge but the rental car company undoubtedly uses an anti-fraud system which might. People use stolen credit cards and fake IDs to [steal rental cars](https://www.claimsjournal.com/news/national/2014/03/12/245815.htm), a VPN or a country mismatch is a huge red flag.

Comment: When I lived at a downtown city I priced rental cars both at the city outlets that were walking distance from my house, and also the airport.  About 1/4 of the time, the airport had the cheapest rate by cheaper enough to justify the time/money of hopping a ride to the airport.

Comment: @user71659 Where I'm from, the bank is likely to refuse the charge if it looks like you're across the world from where they think you are. This is basic anti-fraud. Your online banking system will have an option to declare that you will be travelling in _X_ country between _Y_ and _Z_ dates.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The credit card charge is processed at destination country, and travel charges are supposed to include metadata about this too, so the bank sees the same charge, VPN or not. Besides, it would be a card not present charge, so the bank doesn't need a travel notice.

Comment: @user71659 Now that's a valid counter-argument!

Comment: @user71659 Sure, maybe! But that's not what the answer says, and it still doesn't account for the fact that your bank would have _no idea_ that you used a VPN to place the order. The charge comes in to the bank _from the rental company_. A VPN used to access the rental company's site wouldn't come into play at all in this situation.

Comment: @only_pro You're just being completely pedantic at this point. It's card not present so the merchant holds the risk of fraud, and its the merchant's car at risk, so the merchant implements fraud detection. The point is that there is a real risk of being denied when VPNs are detected. The OP doesn't care who denies it, just that it happens. So please stop picking over tiny words.

Comment: @user71659 I'm not trying to be pedantic, I honestly don't understand what you're talking about. How could the bank detect a VPN? That's a rhetorical question–they cannot. So what exactly do you mean? The _merchant_ could detect the VPN and deny the transaction, but a) this is not common, and b) there's no reason to. All the merchant cares about is getting paid.

Comment: @only_pro Nope, you need to do some basic research. It is very common. Any half-popular online merchant does fraud detection, because they themselves are financially responsible for online credit card fraud, not the bank. If an online transaction is fraudulent, the seller loses 100% of the money. They pass the IP to a service (search for "ip reputation service") which does detect VPNs and anonymizers. They also use services (serch "ecommerce fraud prevention") that take factors like countries, IPs, and transaction patterns and such to tell them whether to accept or deny a transaction.

Comment: @only_pro And, as I pointed out in the link, criminals rent a car with stolen credit cards and fake licenses and drive off with it. The car rental company has far more at stake than the rental fee.

Comment: The issuer of the credit card has the final authority to approve or decline a transaction, once posted by the merchant. The merchant's bank (acquirer) sets the rules to accept transactions - the merchant has very little say in it. If the acquirer accepts the transaction, the issuer can still decline it; since there is a ton of other information that is sent to authorize a charge. Online transactions don't have anything to do with "card not present" which is only for POS transactions. Charges are not "processed at the destination country" but by the scheme and the issuer.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I see you have experience in banking, but I'm having trouble understanding your claims. (E.g Charges are "processed" by multiple companies cooperating; otherwise, it would not be a transaction. Yes, one of them has final authority, but that doesn't seem to add clarity to the discussion.) (I realize that over-simplifying doesn't help, either!)

Comment: In fact, I would be surprised if there were a neat and tidy correspondence between which country you access the site from, and which country the charge come from. I'd also be surprised if every well-known international merchant were as diligent as you say --- what is regulated may well be different from what happens in practice. Whether or not to exploit such a discrepancy is a question for one's spiritual and legal counsel, of course, rather than internet strangers.

Comment: Decent online payment processors probably can tell if the transaction is being done over a VPN with some accuracy.  Basically any nonstandard sort of internet connection can be treated as higher risk.  Whether the merchant is using one of those processors or integrating various risk detection products is another question, of course.  Anyone who thinks it can't be done really is underestimating what can be done with a ton of transaction data.

Comment: @user3761894 , a merchant _could_ know that, but why would he care? If the charge goes through, he has his money. What does he care where in the world you sit when you book?

Comment: @Aganju As I said before, forget fraud of the rental fee, _people steal the $30,000 car_.

Comment: @Aganju chargebacks are a thing.  And in any case, the payment processor is the one who will kill the transaction before the merchant has a chance to accept it.